# How to click on popup contents in Puppeteer?

Tags: javascript, node.js, popup, puppeteer

I open the 'deliver to' popup but am not able to click on the input field and enter information.

```
(async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: false});
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    const url = 'https://www.tntsupermarket.com/eng/store-flyer';
    await page.goto(url, {waitUntil: 'networkidle0'});

    const newPagePromise = new Promise(x => browser.once('targetcreated', target => x(target.page())));
    await page.evaluate(()=> {
        document.querySelector('span[class="deliverCss-city-FJJ"]').click();
    });
    const popup = await newPagePromise;
    await popup.waitForSelector('input[aria-label="Enter your Postal Code"]');
    await popup.focus('input[aria-label="Enter your Postal Code"]');
    await popup.click('input[aria-label="Enter your Postal Code"]');
    await popup.keyboard.type('a2b');

})();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pop-up isn't a new page, just a modal element that's shown with JS and without navigation. Removing the navigation promise gives a pretty clear result:

```js
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer"); // ^13.5.1

let browser;
(async () => {
  browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: false});
  const [page] = await browser.pages();
  const url = "https://www.tntsupermarket.com/eng/store-flyer";
  await page.goto(url, {waitUntil: "networkidle0", timeout: 90000});
  const cityEl = await page.waitForSelector('span[class="deliverCss-city-FJJ"]');
  await cityEl.evaluate(el => el.click());
  const postalSel = 'input[aria-label="Enter your Postal Code"]';
  const postalEl = await page.waitForSelector(postalSel);
  await postalEl.type("a2b");
  await page.waitForTimeout(30000); // just to show that the state is as we wish
})()
  .catch(err => console.error(err))
  .finally(() => browser?.close())
;
```

This is a bit slow; there's an annoying pop-up you might wish to click off instead of using `"networkidle0"`:

```js
// ... same code
  await page.goto(url, {waitUntil: "domcontentloaded", timeout: 90000});
  const closeEl = await page.waitForSelector("#closeActivityPop");
  await closeEl.click();
  const cityEl = await page.waitForSelector('span[class="deliverCss-city-FJJ"]');
// same code ...
```

On quick glance, if the page is cached, the pop-up might not show, so you might want to abort `page.waitForSelector("#closeActivityPop");` after 30 seconds or so and continue with the code without clicking on it, depending on how flexible you want the script to be.

Comment: I see. It worked, and thanks for the additional information!